# Why does Foreman exit when I add a rake assets:precompile task to my Procfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake, foreman

My Ruby on Rails application uses foreman (https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) to manage the processes that need to be started when the app is run.

My `Procfile` looks like this:

```
precompile: bundle exec rake assets:precompile
web: bundle exec puma -e $PUMA_ENV
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
search: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
```

Running `$ foreman start` worked as expected until I added the first line (the `precompile` task).

When I run `$ foreman start` my output looks like this:

```
$ foreman start -e .env.dev
10:30:20 precompile.1 | started with pid 7309
10:30:20 web.1        | started with pid 7310
10:30:20 worker.1     | started with pid 7311
10:30:20 search.1     | started with pid 7312
10:30:22 web.1        | [7310] Puma starting in cluster mode...
10:30:22 web.1        | [7310] * Version 2.8.2 (ruby 2.1.0-p0), codename: Sir Edmund Percival Hillary
10:30:22 web.1        | [7310] * Min threads: 4, max threads: 16
10:30:22 web.1        | [7310] * Environment: development
10:30:22 web.1        | [7310] * Process workers: 2
10:30:22 web.1        | [7310] * Phased restart available
10:30:22 web.1        | [7310] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
10:30:22 web.1        | [7310] Use Ctrl-C to stop
10:30:23 web.1        | [7313] + Gemfile in context: /Users/username/rails_projects/lcms/Gemfile
10:30:23 web.1        | [7314] + Gemfile in context: /Users/username/rails_projects/lcms/Gemfile
10:30:30 web.1        | [7310] - Worker 1 (pid: 7314) booted, phase: 0
10:30:30 worker.1     | [Worker(host:MacBook-Pro.local pid:7311)] Starting job worker
10:30:30 web.1        | [7310] - Worker 0 (pid: 7313) booted, phase: 0
10:30:32 precompile.1 | exited with code 0
10:30:32 system       | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
10:30:32 web.1        | [7310] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
10:30:32 worker.1     | [Worker(host:MacBook-Pro.local pid:7311)] Exiting...
10:30:32 search.1     | exited with code 143
10:30:32 web.1        | [7310] - Goodbye!
10:30:32 web.1        | exited with code 0
10:30:33 worker.1     | exited with code 0
```

I don't know how to get more details on the problem.  I've added `$stdout.sync = true` to my `config/environments/development.rb`, and the output is the same as without.

I've also tried both appending and prepending `RAILS_ENV=development` and `RAILS_ENV=production` to the precompile task.

How can I get my foreman/Procfile setup to precompile assets successfully, and then continue with the other tasks that start the app?

Comment: I suspect that `10:30:32 precompile.1 | exited with code 0` is the end of the `rake assets:precompile` task, the exit code of 0 tells foreman to kill all processes.  I'm not sure how to override that, and if I did, I don't know if that is wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided that my best option is to use a syntax that will execute my `rake assets` tasks prior to booting Puma and only if precompiling is successful.

So, running the commands in order with `&&` between them seems to achieve the result that I desire

```
web: bundle exec rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=$FOREMAN_ENV && bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=$FOREMAN_ENV && bundle exec puma -e $FOREMAN_ENV
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
search: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
```

Comment: For clarity, I'd prefer to see each of these commands on separate lines.  If someone else also chooses to use foreman with Rails and precompile assets on start, then please share your solution for managing this process.

Comment: Thanks! I needed to copy some static files during initialization, && worked!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that as soon as one of the processes in foreman exists, all do. I assume this is by design which makes sense. The application is the combination of running services.

If you want to run one-off tasks you can use foreman run.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `sleep` to the every process after first line

```
web: sleep 1; bundle exec puma -e $PUMA_ENV
worker: sleep 1; bundle exec rake jobs:work
search: sleep 1; bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
```

If it works, remove `sleep 1;` one by one to see what cause problem.